# JPanel not updating, no matter what i try

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, twitter4j

Im making a small program that shows teams/ players/ then their twitter feeds, tweets, etc. My problem seems to be unrelated to that though, it just my jPanel isn't updating. I got pretty far in the project, and i keep throwing random code segments in my method to make it so once i click something, the "left" jpanel either is replaced with the jbuttons, or the jbuttons are put into it, ive tried both. Heres the code segment ive been trying to get to work, which it does, just not as intended.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {        
    System.out.println("You clicked on " + ap.getTeams()  [addPlayers.OPTIC].getTeamName());
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            //JPanel temp = ap.makePanel(ap.getTeams()[ap.OPTIC].getPlayers().get(i).getTwitterScreenName());
            //temp.setBounds(0,(i*125),   450,125);
            //left.add(temp);

            JButton b = new JButton("Test");
            b.setBounds(30,30,30,30);
            left.add(b);
            left.revalidate();
            add(left);
            add(b);
            right.add(b);
            left.setVisible(false);
            left.setVisible(true);

            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }   
}
```

the commented out code is my main code, but i am just using jbuttons to test. As you can see, i just keep adding random bits, hoping something will work. Ive also tried invoke later, but sadly, that didn't work either.Not sure why the jpanels not updating, but any feedback would be great, thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). *"i just keep adding random bits, hoping something will work"* In over a decade of development, I haven't seen 'programming by magic' work even once.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: `"programming by magic"` -- I like that and am gonna have to use it!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  You're most welcome to use the phrase, but please don't use the programming technique.  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Avoid null layout and setBounds since this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. Instead you will want to study and learn the layout managers and then nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager to create pleasing and complex GUI's that look good on all OS's.
2. The best way to swap JPanels or any component is to use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).
3. If still stuck, then post a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's the best way for us to actually see and experience your problem.
4. Don't add a component to more than one container like you're doing with your `b` JButton variable. You're in fact adding it to **three** containers.
5. You seem to be trying to add four JButtons to containers, giving them all the same bounds, one exactly on top of the other?? Sorry, but the more I look at your code, the more screwy it becomes. Again, stop this nonsense, learn about the layout managers at the Swing tutorials, and use them.
6. `"and i keep throwing random code segments in my method to make it so ..."` -- throwing things at the wall to see what sticks is not a good heuristic for creating a program. Start with the knowledge base -- here the Swing tutorials and Java API, then plan your program structure, and then create your code.

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> ..... All im asking is whats the problem with the whole thing not updateing?

If you don't use a CardLayout and change components manually, then you would need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container after the change, and the container should update with its new components. If this does not fix the problem, then likely you have an issue in code not shown us, and you will again then want to create and post a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Again it's the best way for us to actually see and experience your problem.

Comment: My intended goal is to have 4 JPanels created on this click of a button, and then displayed in a certain area, then another button would creat 4 different JPanels, same size and layout/positioning, and put them in that certain area. The reason why the buttons were on top of each other was because i just put that in there to try to figure out why it wasn't updating, that wasn't part of my code.Im familier with most layoutmanagers, and ive tested grid and card, both seemed to wither not work or not be what im looking for. All im asking is whats the problem with the whole thing not updateing?